# PHP nth foreach record

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to do slightly more complicated nth record adjudtments, similar to jQuery's / CSS3 `nth-child(3n-1)` in PHP, so there are three cols per row and the mid one needs to have the class "mid" added. I preferably don't want to use jQuery as there always seems to be a lag from the page load and the class being added.

So something like below but i am aware that this would mean `$zxc % 2`, but we all start somewhere.

```
<?php $zxc = 1; ?>
<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
<div class="theProductListItem<?php if($zxc % (3-1) == 0){?> mid<?php } ?>">
<!--product contents-->
</div>
<?php $zxc++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Why not just if($i == 3) { $i = 1; } then you can always check if $i is 3 or something, it will always be the third record

Comment: any reason why not just use CSS3 `nth-child()`?

Comment: Hi. I don't want the third record, I am looking for the 3n-1th record, or 5n-2 record, or whatever similar.

Comment: @spudley - "I preferably don't want to use jQuery as there always seems to be a lag from the page load and the class being added." in jQuery and CSS3 is too immature and hit and miss for most of my work (cross browser bits and bobs, etc).

Comment: @Daniel: yes, that's why you reset $i every time it hits 3.

Comment: Ahh ok, so everytime it hits 2 out of the 3 ... Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel - I disagree; CSS3 is not too immature. `nth-child` will work in native CSS in every browser in common use other than IE8 or earlier. IE6/7/8 is a dwindling demographic, but we do need to support them, so for old IE versions, you can use Selectivizr or ie9.js to retro-fit support for the `nth-child` selector. Yes, for old IE this might mean a small delay for the javascript to kick in, but the advantage is that all other browsers can be using standard CSS3, and you don't need to write unnecessary page design stuff into your PHP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
if( ($zxc % 3) == 1)
```

Comment: He is looking for 2, 5, 8... . I dont see yours working with that.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks hjpotter92, if(($zxc % 3) == 2) did it.

Comment: @Steve **the mid one needs to have the class**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `% 3` as by definition you want 'every 3rd item'.

Then you have some options, you can start your variable at an offset.
e.g.

```
$x = 2;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    ...
    if ($x % 3 == 0) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You could also start on a more common 0 or 1 and change your comparison.

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    ...
    if ($x % 3 == 1) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Superficially, you could change the last example to this.

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    ...
    if (($x % 3) - 1 == 0) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of accomplishing what you want without having to worry about modulus calculation at all, though granted, it's a bit more verbose. It extends the standard [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/arrayiterator) with some methods to skip records:

```
class NthArrayItemIterator extends ArrayIterator
{
    private $step;
    private $offset;

    public function __construct($array, $step = 1, $offset = 0)
    {
        parent::__construct($array);
        $this->step = $step;
        $this->offset = $offset;
    }

    private function skipn($n)
    {
        echo "skipn($n)\n";
        while ($n-- && $this->valid()) {
            parent::next();
        }
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        parent::rewind();
        $this->skipn($this->offset);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        $this->skipn($this->step);
    }
}

foreach (new NthArrayItemIterator(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 3, 2) as $item) {
    echo "$item<br />";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/UY38g1Tf)

It outputs the third and sixth item in this case.